# Load balancing by HAProxy on coreos cluster

Tags: load, containers, haproxy, coreos

Trying to do simple load balancing using HAProxy on CoreOS (Fault tolerant cluster).  Here is the scenario
1)  Two CoreOs instances are clustered 
2)  One CoreOS  instance (say 41.100.51.011) got 1 HA proxy  and 2 NodeJs container.. So total 3 Docker container
3)  This is fault tolerant scenario so if one instance goes down services would get started in clustered CoreOs instance (41.100.51.001)
4)  Now on the DNS server, what would be correct mapping say for abc.com should it map to 41.100.51.011 or  41.100.51.001
5)  Assuming abc.com map to first one, this goes down and service started running on second instance,  how user would be able to access the site. As DNS server would still be pointing to old IP
6)  How to change DNS server setting to second CoreOS instance in case of it is down and services started running into another instance?
7)  DO we have some other solution or I am not getting it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic event you need is the containers spawning or terminating. This information is in the etcd database which coreos uses. There is a mechanism called 'watch' which will let you do something based upon information changing in etcd. Two examples follow.

You could use a combination of [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd),  [skydns](https://github.com/skynetservices/skydns/) and [registrator](https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator) to provide dns for containers. The basic concept is that as containers are born and die the database (etcd) is updated by registrator including the ip address and service type. The information in etcd is used by skydns to serve dns.

There is a different problem with haproxy, though... You have to configure the haproxy.cfg file with servers in a static config file.  So, when the containers change the haproxy.cfg file gets updated and reloaded. There is a good writeup on how to do this [Between reality and cyberspace](http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/90554410668/easy-scaling-with-docker-haproxy-and-confd).

Of course, if you want to launch multiple haproxies for entrypoint redundancy and multiple containers for service redundancy a combination of both techniques will be needed.

-g